# How to get the element from a jQuery on() event using an ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Previous to using ES6 arrow functions, if I wanted to get the element from a jQuery `on()` click event then I could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.inserted-el', function(event) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

However, with the arrow function, I can no longer access `this` in that way. How do I get hold of the element that was clicked on?

Comment: This should work fine. How do the markup look??

Comment: @Hacketo I've simplified the example, I want to refer to the lexical `this` also within the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [event.currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to refer to the target element of the handler

```js
$(document).on('click', '.inserted-el', function(event) {
  snippet.log('old -> ' + this.innerHTML + ':' + event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
});
$(document).on('click', '.inserted-el', (event) => {
  snippet.log('new -> ' + this.innerHTML + ':' + event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="inserted-el">1</button>
<button class="inserted-el">2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`event.currentTarget`
```

is your friend here.

The reason you can't access it as 'this' is because arrow functions have the same 'this' as their parent scope.

You should also know about `event.target`

http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/